# Extract last line of very long txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very long file containing data ("text.txt") and a single file that contains exactly 1 line that is the last line of text.txt. This single line should be overwritten every 10 minutes (done by a simple chronjob) as text.txt receives another line every 10 minutes.

So based on other code snippets I found on stackoverflow I currently run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys

file = open(sys.argv[1], "r+")

#Move the pointer (similar to a cursor in a text editor) to the end of the file. 
file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

#This code means the following code skips the very last character in the file - 
#i.e. in the case the last line is null we delete the last line 
#and the penultimate one
pos = file.tell() - 1

#Read each character in the file one at a time from the penultimate 
#character going backwards, searching for a newline character
#If we find a new line, exit the search
while pos > 0 and file.read(1) != "\n":
    pos -= 1
    file.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)

#So long as we're not at the start of the file, delete all the characters ahead of this position
if pos > 0:
    file.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
    w = open("new.txt",'w')
    file.writelines(pos)
    w.close()

file.close()
```

With this code I get the error:

> TypeError: writelines() requires an iterable argument

(of course). When using `file.truncate()` I can get rid of the last line in the original file; but I want to keep it there and just extract that last line to new.txt. But I don't comprehend how this works when working with file.seek. So I'd need help for the last part of the code.

`file.readlines()` with `lines[:-1]` does not work properly with such huge files.

Comment: Have you considered just using the command tail? If you just want to read and not write

Comment: What about storing the offset of the 'current' last line (or filesize), and seeking directly to the position in next iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're opening `w`, only to close it without doing anything with it. If you want `new.txt` to have all the text from `file` starting at `pos` and ending at the end, how about:

```
if pos > 0:
    file.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
    w = open("new.txt",'w')
    w.write(file.read())
    w.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, `pos` is an integer which is used to denote the position of first `\n` from the end of the file.

You cannot do - `file.writelines(pos)` , as writelines requires a list of lines. But `pos` is a single integer.

Also you want to write to `new.txt` , so you should use `w` file to write, not `file` . Example -

```
if pos > 0:
    file.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
    w = open("new.txt",'w')
    w.write(file.read())
    w.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following approach:

```
max_line_length = 1000

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f_long, open('new.txt', 'w') as f_new:
    f_long.seek(-max_line_length, os.SEEK_END)
    lines = [line for line in f_long.read().split("\n") if len(line)]
    f_new.write(lines[-1])
```

This will seek to almost the end of the file and read the remaining part of the file in. It is then split into non-empty lines and the last entry is written to `new.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to tail the last 2 lines of a file into a list:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-n 2', '~/path/to/my_file.txt'])
lines = output.split('\n')
```

Now you can get the info you need out of the list `lines`.